# react-native-reanimated interpolate width percentage

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am converting some of my default `Animated` stuff to `react-native-reanimated v2` and can't seem to figure out how to interpolate a value to a string percentage. I also can't find anything related to this in the docs.

Using Animated from react-native I could just do:

```js
width: widthAnim.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 1],
   outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
})
```

But the `interpolate()` function from reanimated only takes number params, so how can I animate the width then?

```js
interpolate(widthAnim.value, [0, 1], ['0%', '100%'])
// err: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use template literal

```js
width: `${widthAnim.value * 100}%`
```

Check out more [official example](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/4d99cb76c0d524366aacb56335801f82dc68a2ae/app/src/examples/WobbleExample.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

A full example to complete the previous response:

```
const searchViewAnimatedWidth = useSharedValue(0);

const searchBoxAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  const interpolatedWidth = interpolate(
    searchViewAnimatedWidth.value,
    [0, 1],
    [40, 100],
    { extrapolateRight: Extrapolation.CLAMP }
  );
  return {
    width: withTiming(`${interpolatedWidth}%`, {
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }),
  };
});

<Animated.View 
    style={{...otherStyles,...searchBoxAnimatedStyle}}>

   ... 

</Animated.View>
```

And in your trigger

```
onPress={() => {
  searchViewAnimatedWidth.value = searchViewAnimatedWidth.value == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}}
```